# How to add public cert to google storage bucket

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform

Currently, i have a static website hosted on google cloud storage and the encrypted via ssl using basic cloudflare setup. Now I want to connect to my springboot application which has its own self signed certificate. How can make this connection. Should I add the pubic key somehow to the storage bucket or is there something else to this?

Answer (score 1):

Your website is hosted on Cloud Storage, but it runs on your browser. If you use a self signed certificate on your backend, the browser can raise a warning because it doesn't trust this certificate.

So, you need to add the public key to your browser, not to your hosting system. or use a let's encrypt certificate, it's free and easy!

Comment: Where do I need to use the `lets encrypt` certificate....Do I need to add it to my `springboot` application. The reason I ask this is because the `static part` of my applicaiton(between `browser` and `storage`) is already `https`. My trouble is with the part between `storage` and my `compute vm` on which the `springboot` application is present.

Comment: Also, I tried to add a self-signed cert to my `springboot` applicaiton. I got `ERR_CERT_INVALID`